# Adobe Air how to bind ANE files

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I'm thinking if is possible to connector to bind somehow many ANE files?

For example if I have **Vibration ANE** , **GoogleMaps ANE** and **AdMob ANE.**.. I have to import each ANE, **one by one** in my project. My question is: could be there a solution to connect ANES togeter and import only one file and inside this file to be all my ANE...??

Thank you.

Comment: no it's not possible

Comment: thank you. How about a SWC file? can it package the ane files?

Comment: I have a package which contains 6 classes. How can I export it to SWC from Flash Profesional CC ?

Comment: ane and swc are not the same things. You can't put an ane inside a swc.

Comment: thanks. If you want post the answer, I will accept it. Have a great day!